# Subquery - on clause column not visible

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I facing with a strange situation with a sql query on mysql 5.1.41 environment on a Ubuntu machine.

The code follow

```
SELECT spedizione0_.idspedizione,
    spedizione0_.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(n.idnegozio)
        FROM negozio n
        LEFT JOIN confezione c
            ON n.idnegozio = c.idnegozio
                AND c.idspedizione = spedizione0_.idspedizione
        WHERE n.datainizio <= spedizione0_.dataspedizione
            AND n.datafine >= spedizione0_.dataspedizione
            OR c.idspedizione != 0
        ) AS formula5_
FROM orocashgenerico.spedizione spedizione0_
ORDER BY spedizione0_.dataspedizione DESC
```

In this case the error says : **[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'spedizione0_.idspedizione' in 'on clause'**

The only way to run this query is to change the .. on n.idnegozio=c.idnegozio and c.idspedizione=spedizione0_.idspedizione into on n.idnegozio=c.idnegozio and c.idspedizione=12

The most strange things for me is: if i move the and condition to the where clause the query run correctly, of course the results is not what I excepted.

My question is where is the problem?
Is something related to the MySQL version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `spedizione0_` is not found with the scope of your subquery. Try this one,

```
SELECT  spedizione0_.idspedizione,                     // add additionl columns
        COUNT(n.idnegozio) AS formula5_                
FROM    spedizione spedizione0_
        LEFT JOIN confezione c
            ON c.idspedizion = spedizione0_.idspedizione
        LEFT JOIN negozio n
            ON n.idnegozio = c.idnegozio
WHERE   (
            n.datainizio <= spedizione0_.dataspedizione AND 
            n.datafine >= spedizione0_.dataspedizione
        )
            OR c.idspedizione != 0
GROUP By spedizione0_.idspedizione
ORDER BY spedizione0_.dataspedizione DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

as I can see, you are using the wrong syntax here. When you use a Left Outer join, you cannot mention more than one condition in ON clause.
In your case, you need to use one more Left join clause after that ON clause to join 3rd table which is giving error.

Comment: Thats not true, if i use a "ON n.idnegozio = c.idnegozio AND c.idspedizione = 1" the query run. So i can do more than one condition in a ON clause....

Comment: Ya that's right, but in your case since you are joining 3rd table, it can not be done..